# Start a project with Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks

What are those drawbacks if I start a project with CI nowdays? What kind of issues could appear in the near future (1-2 years)?
I'm not following the CI development in realtime, but maybe it won't get fresh. I have been coding in CI for years, i know it and like it. I have some new projects which i'm going to develop with CI. I'm planning to move later to a newer framework like laravel, but currently i have no time to learn something new and using for live projects.

Comment: #5 this week https://github.com/trending?l=php&since=weekly #4 this month https://github.com/trending?l=php&since=monthly Recent Posts by derek jones of ellis and narf http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/234985/P30

Comment: Thanks for the answers for everybody, also the moderators help me in this question. I read a lot of articles about whats trending what is "dead", and wanted to get answers for specific issues. But nothing "special" and it's more likely "opinion-based"! Back to working.. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The current "problems" of CI are : Doesn't follow PSR-0,1,2 coding style nor the latest PHP functions (no namespace, forget about composer, etc). So this can feel "old" if you develop with up to date frameworks.

However, CIv3 is on its way (you can find info about it [here](http://lonnieezell.com/whats-new-in-codeigniter-3/) and get it [here](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/tree/release/3.0)). And it's already usuable. It's also trying to stick with the coding style of [FIG](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/tree/master/accepted).

So should you use CI2 ? nope. CI3 ? why not ! You already know CI, so this should be much easier than learning a new framework. But if you want to see something new and more up-to-date try Laravel, PHPixie or Phalcon (there are many others).

**EDIT** : To those saying CI is dead. Just look at the [commits release 3.0](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/commits/release/3.0) & [develop branch](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/commits/develop).

Answer (score 0):

From http://heybigname.com/2012/05/06/why-codeigniter-is-dead:

- PHP 5.2 with no new >5.3 PHP features
- No modular design patterns (limited).

I'm exactly in the same situation as you, and I'm planning to move to Laravel (a college of mine who has always worked with CI is using it and he has told me that it's a good framework and it's easy to migrate from CI) or Symphony, specially with Sylex (easy to start with) but is drawing me back because of the learning curve.